# Swift Constraints Don't Take After Rotate

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton, nslayoutconstraint

I am creating a `UIButton` programmatically in the code and am constraining it to the top and the right of the `ViewController`. When the `ViewController` loads, the `UIButton` is in the correct position on the screen. The problem comes when I rotate the device, the constraints don't seem to have taken. Here is the code I use to create the `UIButton`:

```
let xValue = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width - 44
let closeButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: xValue, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: 44, height: 44)))

closeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "close"), forState: .Normal)
closeButton.addTarget(self, action: "closeClicked", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)

self.view.addSubview(closeButton)

self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: closeButton, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: closeButton, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
```

Is there something else I need to do to ensure the constraints are applied after an orientation change?

Comment: What device are you testing on?

Comment: I've testing with simulators  (iPad Air, iPhone 6, iPhone 6+) running iOS 8.3 and iPad 2 and iPod 5 gen running iOS 8.4. All of them exhibit the same behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't combine `frames` with constraints.  By default, iOS will convert your frame to constraints, and that is causing a conflict with the constraints you are setting.  After creating your button, you need to call:

**For Swift 1.2:**

```
closeButton.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
```

**For Swift 2.0:**

```
closeButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

so that iOS doesn't try to convert your frame into constraints.  Then you need to add two additional constraints for the width and height of your button:

```
closeButton.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: closeButton, attribute: .Width,
  relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 44))

closeButton.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: closeButton, attribute: .Height,
  relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 44))
```

Since your button is no longer using the frame, you can create it with:

```
let closeButton = UIButton()
```

Now your button will stick to the upper right of your screen in all orientations for all devices.

Answer (score 0):

All You need is to disable animation (uncheck "Animation" checkbox) on segue and then will be no need to update constraints.
Can be found in Segue options in right panel while editing storyboard.